# Проблемы с запуском приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, отладка

При запуске приложения в студии на устройстве появляется: `Waiting For Debugger`-сообщение, хотя режим отладки в студии не включал, а делал обычный запуск. Как решить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запускаете на реальном устройстве или на эмуляторе?

Comment: На реальном устройстве

Comment: Попробуйте перезагрузить сам девайс